# Extracting most important words from Elasticsearch index, using Node JS client

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, word2vec

Inspired by the following [git](https://github.com/DiceTechJobs/ConceptualSearch) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYOkb1BQG2E) I'm trying to create a conceptual search for my domain, using `word2vec` as a synonyms filter for my queries.

Giving the following document structure:

```
{
        "_index": "conversations",
        "_type": "conversation",
        "_id": "103130",
        "_score": 0.97602403,
        "_source": {
          "context": "Welcome to our service, how can I help? do you offer a free trial",
          "answer": "Yes we do. Here is a link for our trial account."
        }
      }
```

I would like to iterate through the entire index and extract words with "higher significant" (tf-idf ?).
Once I will have the top 100 words list, I'll create a synonyms filter using `word2vec`.

My question is: How can this be done using ES Node JS client?

Comment: tf-idf is not defined for a collection, it is defined for a document. You would end up with the idf part, it is very doubtful that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you suggest a better approach to extract significant words out of the index?

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz can you explain how your solution would be better than the function already provided by the suggester?

Comment: Given a query, we could calculate tf-idf for terms in the query results as compared to the entire document space. I take it from your question that you want to do so prior to receiving a query. You could try either comparing your documentspace against another more general one (fi. the Internet, or Wikipedia) or you could calculate the information gain of all terms (or any other feature selection method).

Comment: Do you mean the solution on the git project? If so, I'm just trying to implement something similar on Elastic instead of SOLR. The git also includes an extract keywords solution, which is a bit confusing for me

Comment: @SvanBalen, you are right I would like to do so prior to receiving a query. can you elaborate on 'calculate the information gain of all terms'

Comment: The significance of a term normaly depends on something. In feature selection what you do is you evaluate a feature (term in this case) on how well it seperates a target class. Since we are lacking a target, we would basically be evaluating on how well it devides the search space, which brings us back at document frequency. But somehow I doubt that is what you are looking for. I suggest you look into extracting terms that are significant for your search space (high frequency in search space low document frequency on the internet) or terms that have been searched often in your application.

Comment: @SvanBalen, I see your point ... so what exactly the author of the above git repository means by  "_extract_keywords.py - (optional) If you don't have a good and extensive set of keyphrases from your domain (e.g. your top 5,000 seach keywords and phrases, phrases being the important part) or you want to increase coverage beyond this list, run this script to extract all keywords and phrases above a specified document frequency threshold._"?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to read the actual code, I just reacted to the idea of using tf-idf. Scanning over it I say that it extracts words and phrases that occur in a certain percentage of documents (corresponding to a df that divides the search space into somehwat even parts) and then tries to find ngrams that cover those words. PS: I recommend inspecting AR1's question and explain what you are looking to add to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html

Comment: you could iterate all documents, for each doc retrieve the terms and  calculate the tf-idf value of each term. then count how many times the heights value term appeared in your documents, then take the top n terms.

Answer (score 1):

Tf-Idf  of documents is typically used to find the similarity of documents (using Cosine similarity,  euclidean distance etc)

Tf or term frequency indicates frequency of a word in the document. Higher the frequency of the word, higher the importance of the word.

Idf or inverse document frequency indicates the number of documents(of input collection) that contains the word. More rare the word, higher the importance of the word.

If we just use TF to build document vector, we are prone to spam because common words(for eg: pronouns, conjunctions etc) gain more importance. Hence, combination of td-idf gives better meaning and indicates the real significance of the word. Or in other words to rank words of a document based on the significance, it is not advised to calculate just the tf of each word, instead use tf-idf on the entire input collection and rank based on the tf-idf value which shows the real significance of keywords.

Have a look at sample python solution for calculating tf-idf value for json tweets list and finding the similar tweets.

[Github Sample](https://github.com/johnugeorge/data-mining/blob/master/page-rank/part1.py)

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Search provides a very specific data aggregation which allow you to extract "Significant Keywords" for a subset of your Index [1]

To elaborate what is significant you need a foreground (the subset of docs you want to analyse) and a background (the entire corpus) .

As you may realize, to identify a term as significant you need to compare how is appearing in your corpus in comparison to something else ( for example a generic corpus).
You may find some archive that contains a sort of general IDF score for terms ( Reuter corpus, brown corpus, wikipedia ect ect).
Then you can :
Foreground document set -> your corpus
Background document set -> generic corpus

[1] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html